# How to get color coded Quran with tajweed rule

Tags: xetex, color, polyglossia, arabic

I would like to get Colour Coded Al-Quran text with Tajweed Rules. I can write Arabic text with latex but they are not color coded. How do I get color coded text?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia,quran}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}



\begin{Arabic}
\lineskiplimit=-1000pt
\setstretch{1.2}
\quransurah[114]
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

I would like to get as below :

[image]

Comment: @ DG' No I am asking this type of solution.

Comment: Please formulate your question more clearly!

Answer (score 1):

Here an option with `lualatex` engine and `babel` package (you need a recent distribution)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luacolor}

\newcommand\colr[2]{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color{#1}%
    #2%
  \endgroup
}


\begin{luacode}
function colored ( s )
 s = unicode.utf8.gsub(s, "[ًٌٍَُِْ]","\\colr{red}{%1}")
  return  s 
end
\end{luacode}

\def\FormatOn{%
\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", colored, "colored")}}
\def\FormatOff{%
\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer","colored")}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\centering\Huge

\FormatOn

تَجرِيبْ بسمِ اللهِ الرحمَانِ الرَحِيمْ

\FormatOff

\begin{luacode}
function colored ( s )
 s = unicode.utf8.gsub(s, "[بم]","\\colr{blue}{%1}")
  return  s 
end
\end{luacode}


\FormatOn

تَجرِيبْ بسمِ اللهِ الرحمَانِ الرَحِيمْ


\FormatOff

تَجرِيبْ بسمِ اللهِ الرحمَانِ الرَحِيمْ


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ SalimBou It not the solution what I was asked.

Comment: You need it with `Quran` package?

Comment: @ SalimBou Yes.